Workflow issue - InstancePersistenceCommand was interrupted - instance key {GUID} was not associated to an instance
I am working on a web application which has using workflow services with persistence.
When calling the workflow service after passing the required data.I am getting the below error.

The execution of an InstancePersistenceCommand was interrupted because
the instance key 982f042b-f3ea-17c6-1e94-55aceb@b360d T was not
associated to an instance. This can occur because the instance or key
has been cleaned up, or because the key is invalid. The key may be
invalid if the message it was generated from was sent at the wrong
time or contained incorrect correlation data

However what I am passing to instance id to workflow call is different from error message.
For persistence what I have done is I have created SqlWorkflowPersistenceStore object in Global.aspx file since connection string is in encrypted format.
Please guide me on this I am not able to understand the issue.
Thanks.
Actually before Sqlworkflowinstancestore tag was there inside web config file but connection string is encrypted I had to remove that. After that it is not working.
